# C++ std::string::find неверно работает

Tags: c++, строки

Нужно распарсить строку, для этого необходимо найти позицию знака

> ^

это действие выполняю при помощи данного куска кода

```
 pos = 0;
 if( pos = part.find( "^" ) != std::string::npos )
 {
     n = atoi( part.substr( pos + 1 ).c_str() );
 }
```

при вводе строки

> 2*x

или

> x^2

данный код работает как часы (адекватно находит позицию или отсутствие знака), но если ввести

> 2*x^2

то `pos` становиться равным 1, хотя должен быть равен 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Согласно приоритету операторов

```
pos = part.find( "^" ) != std::string::npos
```

выполняется так:

сначала выполняется `part.find( "^" )`, результат сравнивается с `std::string::npos` и результат сравнения присваивается `pos`.

Т.е. как

```
pos = (part.find( "^" ) != std::string::npos)
```

Вы же, наверное, хотели получить функциональность

```
(pos = part.find( "^" )) != std::string::npos
```